# Set SignalR client connectionid from configuration but not autogenerated

Tags: console, client, signalr

My SignalR client is Console Application
I want to set the ConnectionId for my console application (SignalRClient)

My thought is, in my console application config file, I set the ConnectionId, say, in app.config, I set a property "MyConnectionId" with value "123-123-123-123" and that ID ("123-123-123-123") should be used as SignalRClientConnectionId instead of auto-generated GUID.

Is this possible? If so, how?

The intention behind it is, I want to identify all the clients connected to my hubs, so that, I can send the data to respective SignalRClient/ConsoleApp

Hope, I'm clear.

Thank you.

Comment: You can't set connection id - what if you set the same value for multiple connections? The server creates connectionIds and you can access them on the server side. If you need connection ids on the client you can send them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot provide a custom ConnectionId. This ConnectionId is always generated by SignalR itself.

For your intention what you can do is store the information of your console apps with along the ConnectionID. (ex:- in a database table where columns will be console app name and ConnectionID). By doing that you can identify which ConnectionID belongs to which console application so you can identify and send them separately as you want.